# Reader-Writer lock not working properly

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, writer, reader

I have made a reader-writer(with a writers bias, ex. no reading while writing) lock in Python which does not work properly due to one of the writer not releasing the lock and even though it prints the message and is supposed to release the lock afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock
import time
import datetime

resource = 'hello world'
lock = Lock()
counter = 0
Lcounter = 0

class WriterA(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            global lock
            global resource
            global counter
            global Lcounter
            time.sleep(5)
            if Lcounter == 1:
                if counter == -1:
                    print ("WriterA is trying to acquire the lock")
                    lock.acquire()

                    print ("WriterA acquired the lock")
                    time.sleep(5)
                    now = datetime.datetime.now()
                    temp = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
                    now_string = now.strftime(temp)
                    resource = now_string

                    print ("WriterA releasing the lock")
                    lock.release()
                    counter = 0

class WriterB(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            global lock
            global resource
            global counter
            global Lcounter
            time.sleep(5)
            if Lcounter == 2:
                if counter == -1:
                    print ("WriterB is trying to acquire the lock")
                    lock.acquire()

                    print ("WriterB acquired the lock")
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print resource
                    resource = (resource [::-1])

                    print ("WriterB is releasing the lock")
                    lock.release()
                    counter = 0

class Reader(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global resource
        global counter
        global Lcounter
        if counter >= 0:
            time.sleep(5)
            print ("Reader is trying to acquire the resource")

            print ("Reader acquired the resource")
            time.sleep(5)
            temp = resource
            print ("The message in %s is %s " % (self.name, temp))
            Lcounter += 1
            counter = -1

Reader().start()
time.sleep(5)
WriterA().start()
time.sleep(5)
Reader().start()
time.sleep(5)
WriterB().start()
time.sleep(5)
Reader().start()
```

The output:

```
Reader is trying to acquire the resource
Reader acquired the resource
The message in Thread-6 is hello world 
WriterA is trying to acquire the lock
WriterA acquired the lock
WriterA releasing the lock
Reader is trying to acquire the resource
Reader acquired the resource
The message in Thread-10 is 06/05/2015 14:55:14 
WriterB is trying to acquire the lock
WriterB acquired the lock
06/05/2015 14:55:14
WriterB is releasing the lock
```

This is the output I got with @User hanging_threads:

```
Reader is trying to acquire the resource
Reader acquired the resource
The message in Thread-7 is hello world 
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
WriterA is trying to acquire the lock
WriterA acquired the lock
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 400, in OnRun
    cmd = self.cmdQueue.get(1, 0.1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 177, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
WriterA releasing the lock
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
Reader is trying to acquire the resource
Reader acquired the resource
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 44, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 400, in OnRun
    cmd = self.cmdQueue.get(1, 0.1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 177, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
The message in Thread-11 is 06/05/2015 15:18:58 
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1107, in _exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 949, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 20, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
WriterB is trying to acquire the lock
WriterB acquired the lock
06/05/2015 15:18:58
WriterB is releasing the lock
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1107, in _exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 949, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 20, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 400, in OnRun
    cmd = self.cmdQueue.get(1, 0.1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 177, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 44, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1107, in _exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 949, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 20, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 44, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1107, in _exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 949, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 20, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 44, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1107, in _exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 949, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/Abdulkadir/PycharmProjects/labb5/labb5_final.py", line 20, in run
    time.sleep(5)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
--------------------    Thread 11612    --------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 267, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 227, in OnRun
    self._py_db_command_thread_event.wait(0.5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but you have no lock around `counter`.  Test and set is not atomic.  You should be using a semaphore for this purpose.

Comment: To put it another way, `counter` is also a shared resource and access to it must be coordinated among the threads, too.

Comment: @cdarke my I haven't put any locks on the readers but only on the writers and the counter is supposed to work in a way so as to pick who gets access to the shared resource, 0 = readers, -1 = writerA and writerB. The problem is that it rarely lets go of the lock after finish writerA.

Comment: @martineau Ah alright, that is something I'll try thanks.

Comment: Also, instead of using `lock.acquire()` and explicit `lock.release()` calls, consider using `with lock:` blocks to simplify your code.

Comment: @martineau What difference does that make?

Comment: Instead of `lock.acquire()`, `...lines of code...`, then remembering to `lock.release()`, you can have `with lock:`, `...lines of code...`. `Lock`s are [context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html?highlight=contextmanager#pep-343).

Comment: Please post your output and let us know how you actually run your program.

Comment: @laike9m I've done some changes but I still get the same result, also I've added the output.

Comment: If you do not know where you are stuck, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921525/1320237

Comment: "one of the writer not releasing the lock", which one?