# Pyro4 RPC blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous, rpc, python-multiprocessing

I am currently doing development on a high performance numeric calculations system that posts it results to a web server. We use flask on a seperate process to serve the web page to keep everything interactive and use websockets to send the data to a JS plotter. The calculations are also split using multiprocessing for performance reasons.

We are currently using Pyro4 to get parameters updated in the calculations from the server. However, if the number of updates per second gets high on our Pyro4 settings object it starts blocking and makes it impossible to update any parameters until we restart the server. The proxy calls are made inside of an async websocket callback.

We are currently not getting any tracebacks, nor exceptions which makes debugging this all tricky. Are there any other people that have a lot of experience with Pyro in this context?

Pyro daemon init code:

```
Pyro4.config.SERVERTYPE = "multiplex"
daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()
ns = Pyro4.locateNS()
settings = cg.Settings(web_opt, src_opt, rec_opt, det_opt)
uri = daemon.register(settings)
ns.register("cg.settings", uri)
daemon.requestLoop()
```

Settings class:

```
class Settings(object):

def __init__(self, web_opt, src_opt, rec_opt, det_opt):
    self.pipes = [web_opt, src_opt, rec_opt, det_opt]

def update(self, update):
    [pipe.send(update) for pipe in self.pipes]
```

Proxy call:

```
def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    data = json.loads(payload)
    self.factory.content.set_by_uuid(data['id'], data['value'], self.client_address)
    settings = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:cg.settings")
    values = self.factory.content.values
    settings.update(values)
    settings._pyroRelease()
```

Comment: 1. What are `web_opt, src_opt, rec_opt, det_opt` ? 2. Suggestion: I know that Windows-pipes have a limited number of bytes (4096) until they block writing. Can you debug print and make sure that `pipe.send` is not blocking? e.g. print before and after and see where it blocks? 3. Also consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921525/1320237

Comment: Dude you're my hero! You were absolutely right, the blocking problems were caused by the pipes. They were Python multiprocessing pipes, although they ran on Linux, they still stopped working after a while, because were full (we think). We replaced them with queues which we dequeue when they get too full. Thanks a bunch!