# why open a file is locking my python app

Tags: python, python-2.5

I've a python25 app that run daemonized. It uses a log in memory, and I want to log to a file also. This is the original method for logging:

```
def add_to_request_log(self, data):
    self.__lock.acquire()

    self.__request_log += data + "\n"

    self.__lock.release()
```

I've added this to it:

```
    f = open('server.log', 'a')
    f.write(data + "\n")
    f.close()
```

But for some reason seems like the app got stuck on that point, because is not doing what is suppose to do, if I remove that lines it works normally. I tried adding the lines before, between and after the `lock` but it's same behaviour.

Also, as it is a daemonized app i'm not sure how to debug it.

Pd. This is my first day with python.

Comment: Do you know exactly which line it is getting stuck on?

Comment: No, I dont know which line exactly, the process is not dying, just is not executing what is after the log method. If I remove lines it works normally.

Comment: Depending on how you have started the daemonized app , maybe you can try putting some `print` statements to see where exactly it is getting locked? Or do you have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where the same issue can be reproduced? As it is right now, I cannot see any places in the above code where it would get locked.

Comment: Sometimes print statements or error output will stop a daemon.

Comment: Try to add print statements between each line and see where it gets stuck. Also you can try out [hanging_threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921525/1320237) to see where it stops. It may work under Python 2.5. Also you should surround your locked section with a `self.__lock.acquire(); try: ... ; finally: self.__lock.release()` to avoid locking in error cases.